# sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix" transform into dataframes and it's use for simultaneously regressions in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, sparse-matrix

I have 20 variables of which i have perform multiple *LASSO* regression in *R*. I have take a predictor, and regressing it against every other predictor in the model with the following code

```
library(readxl)
data <-read_excel("data.xlsx")
library(glmnet)
library(coefplot)

A <- as.matrix(data)
results <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(A)), function(i) {
  list(
    fit_lasso = glmnet(A[, -i], A[, i], standardize = T, alpha = 0.9), 
    cvfit = cv.glmnet(A[, -i] , A[, i] , standardize = TRUE , type.measure = "mse" , nfolds = 5 , alpha = 0.9)
  )
})

   #display only the non zero coefficients
    coefficients <- lapply(results, function(x, fun) fun(coef(x$cvfit, s = "lambda.min")), function(x) x[x[, 1L] != 0L, 1L, drop = FALSE])
```

Resulting in `ncol(data)` different `sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"` in one list. display them looks like this for all `ncol(data)` variables:

```
> coefficients 
[[1]]
10 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                        1
(Intercept) -2.214861e+03
X3           2.812453e-05
X5           5.841003e-01
X6           5.428515e+00
X7           1.080925e+01
X8           2.454695e+01
X10          3.917866e-01
X12          2.488678e+00
X13          5.441626e+00
X14          2.400565e-01

[[2]]
6 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                        1
(Intercept) -7.179757e-01
X3           6.563784e-09
X6           1.867302e-02
X8           1.854556e-01
X10         -2.601140e-03
X13          9.105201e-01
```

I want to be able to extract those variables in a data frame in order to use them later for regression. For one of the `sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"` (*let's use the first one X1*), i manage to use this in order to create a dataframe

```
results[[1L]]$cvfit$lambda.min
coeffs<-coef(results[[2L]]$cvfit, s = "lambda.min")

summs <- summary(coeffs)

ssVarX1 <- data.frame(variables      = rownames(coeffs)[summs$i],
           coefficient      = summs$x)
```

which results in:

```
    variables   coefficient
1  (Intercept) -2.214861e+03
2           X3  2.812453e-05
3           X5  5.841003e-01
4           X6  5.428515e+00
5           X7  1.080925e+01
6           X8  2.454695e+01
7          X10  3.917866e-01
8          X12  2.488678e+00
9          X13  5.441626e+00
10         X14  2.400565e-01
```

Although, i some cases ssVarX can be empty of variables and then the result has this form

```
     variable coefficient
1 (Intercept)    106.0629
```

How can i simultaneously create dataframes for all existing `sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"`, with each one having the name `ssVarX[i], i=1,...,ncol(data)` ?

Based on comments most part have been done with the following code

```
library(readxl)
data <-read_excel("data.xlsx")
library(glmnet)
library(coefplot)

A <- as.matrix(data)
results <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(A)), function(i) {
  list(
    fit_lasso = glmnet(A[, -i], A[, i], standardize = T, alpha = 0.9), 
    cvfit = cv.glmnet(A[, -i] , A[, i] , standardize = TRUE , type.measure = "mse" , nfolds = 5 , alpha = 0.9)
  )
})
coefficients <- lapply(results, function(x, fun) fun(coef(x$cvfit, s = "lambda.min")), function(x) x[x[, 1L] != 0L, 1L, drop = FALSE])
list2env(`names<-`(
  lapply(coefficients, function(x) data.frame(variable = row.names(x), coefficient = unname(x[, 1L]))), 
  paste0("ssVarX", seq_along(coefficients))
), envir = .GlobalEnv)

`names<-`(lapply(ls.str(pattern = "ssVarX"), function(x) {
  is <- as.integer(sub("(ssVar)?X", "", c(x, get(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)$variable[-1])))
  if (length(is) == 1) is <- c(is, seq_along(data)[-is])
  as.matrix(coef(lm(data = data[, is])))
}), ls.str(pattern = "ssVarX"))
```

But even though the number of the choosen explanatory variables are the correct in all cases, the corresponding models do not use the right variables that exists in`ssVarX` dataframes. I want it to regress each Xi as predictor against the ssVarX indicated variables and to be extract from `data`. Why this happening? How can i also display the summary results of each regression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
lapply(coefficients, function(x) data.frame(variable = row.names(x), coefficient = unname(x[, 1L])))
```

**Update**

```
list2env(`names<-`(
  lapply(coefficients, function(x) data.frame(variable = row.names(x), coefficient = unname(x[, 1L]))), 
  paste0("ssVarX", seq_along(coefficients))
), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

**Update 2**

```
`names<-`(lapply(ls.str(pattern = "ssVarX"), function(x) {
  is <- as.integer(sub("(ssVar)?X", "", c(x, get(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)$variable[-1])))
  if (length(is) == 1) is <- c(is, seq_along(data)[-is])
  as.matrix(coef(lm(data = data[, is])))
}), ls.str(pattern = "ssVarX"))
```

**Update 3**

How about doing it this way?

```
ssVarX <- lapply(coefficients, function(x) data.frame(variable = row.names(x), coefficient = unname(x[, 1L])))

lm_results <- lapply(seq_along(ssVarX), function(i, df) {
  x_vars <- df[[i]]$variable[-1L]
  if (length(x_vars) == 0) x_vars <- "."
  fml <- as.formula(paste0("X", i, " ~ ", paste(x_vars, collapse = " + ")))
  lm(fml, data = data)
}, ssVarX)
```

To retrieve `coefficients` from the `lm` results:

```
lapply(lm_results, function(x) as.matrix(coef(x)))
```

To retrieve `formula` from the `lm` results:

```
lapply(lm_results, function(x) formula(x))
```

To just print everything to the console:

```
lm_results
```

If still having errors this time, please show me the wrong formula.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222570/discussion-on-answer-by-ekoam-sparse-matrix-of-class-dgcmatrix-transform-into).